# Firebase functions is caching non-existing Auth0 user access token

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, auth0, cache-control

I'm currently using Firebase cloud functions as my mobile app's backend and I'm using Auth0 as my authentication provider.

My problem is that I've used Postman to send test login requests to my API and I'm able to get a valid JWT. I then deleted the user account through Auth0's user management panel and used Postman to test the login function again to see the type of response I would receive. Instead of receiving any errors, I receive a new valid JWT which allows me to access protected routes even though the user does not exist.

I've tried setting the response cache control to "no-store" and yet I'm able to receive a valid JWT. What could the reason be?

Comment: Possibly issue is from firebase side. Please check the [following article](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on how to report an issue to google.

Comment: I've come to find that Firebase Functions caches incoming requests and depending on several factors of the request, it will respond with the same response it has previously returned. For example, if the request is coming from the same client, with the same request data (in this case login credentials), it will return the same access token. I am yet to find a solution to this problem.